# HTML/CSS H2 text not showing

Tags: html, css

Whatever i do the text wont show up here is the code

I tried margin and padding it just fricks up my h1 and p elements and i dont know what to do

```css
*{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 .nav{
     z-index: 300;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: flex-end;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     background: red;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
 h1,p{
     color: white;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     padding-left: 160px;
}
 body{
     z-index: 100;
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     width: auto;
     height: 100vh;
     border-radius: 0px;
     background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #3a3d40 0%, #181719 100%);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     margin : 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 #welcome-section{
     justify-content: center;
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
     z-index: 1000;
     text-align: center;
     margin-top: 160px;
}
 h1{
     font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
     font-size: 50px;
     font-weight: 150;
     padding-top: 300px;
}
 .welcum {
     z-index: 2;
     font-size: 1.4rem;
     font-weight:0;
     font-style: italic;
     color: orangered;
     font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
 html{
     scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
 a {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     margin-left: 30px;
     padding: 7px;
     font-size: 22px;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .textov{
     justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
   <a href="#welcome-section">About</a>
   <a href="#projects">Work</a>
   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</nav>
<header  id="welcome-section">
   <h1 class="title">Hey I am Matija</h1>
   <p class="welcum">a web developer</p>
</header>
<div id="projects">
   <h3 class="textov">My Projects</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't add nonsense text in lieu of describing the problem.  Which specific content are you referring to in the example?  The "My Projects" text?  Something else?

Comment: There is no H2 tag in your html

Comment: `margin-top: 160px;` is your issue. Remove it.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot i changed it to h3 so here is the problem. The h3 element My Projects wont show on my live preview no matter what  i do,  added a margin-top: 1000px and its shows on the bottom of the page but i cant use margin-left or align-text center because it messes up the h1 and p and still wont move after that

Comment: @epascarello i tried but then it isn't doing anything

Comment: @Matija911: The "My Projects" text is "behind" the red banner.  Where did you intend to place it?  Do you just want to add a margin or padding to the top of that element to push it lower than the red banner?  Something else?  Taking a step back... This layout is *very confusing*.  Over-engineered combinations of margin and padding to place elements on a page is going to cause more problems than it solves.  It's not clear what the intended resulting layout *should* be, but this isn't how to achieve it at all.

Comment: @David i want to add "My Projects" beneath the original background "linear-gradient()" one and its not doing anything if i try to add a margin left or something the other elements move but not the "My Projects" text. and can you please help me with the margin and padding so the layout is better, thanks in advance!

Comment: @Matija911: Well, in the *current* layout and styling you can achieve that by adding a `margin-top` or `padding-top` to that element.  But I highly recommend abandoning the current layout and styling and starting again with something simpler.  Margins and paddings are for adding margins and paddings to the element itself, not for tweaking where that element should be placed on the overall page.

Comment: @David okay, but if i dont add padding then my text wont be where i want it to be, do i have an alternative that doesent tweak it?

Comment: @Matija911: Maybe you want to use `flex-direction: column` on the `body` element instead?  Again, we don't know what this layout *should* look like.  (As an aside... For flex layouts in general I *highly recommend* bookmarking this reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @David okay, thanks for the help ill check the flexbox  guide out!

Comment: There's no `<h2>` in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

I removed a few unnecessary CSS directives to repair your code.

The items removed were left as-is but XXX'd out so you can easily see what was changed.

There was no need to use z-index in your code (use z-index sparingly). Also, you do not wish to limit your page size to the height of the screen, so changed your `height` directive on the body element to `min-height`.

```css
*{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 .nav{
     XXXz-index: 300;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: flex-end;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     background: red;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
 h1,p{
     color: white;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     padding-left: 160px;
}
 body{
     XXXz-index: 100;
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     XXXwidth: auto;
     min-height: 100vh; /* <----------- */
     border-radius: 0px;
     background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #3a3d40 0%, #181719 100%);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     margin : 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 #welcome-section{
     justify-content: center;
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
     XXXz-index: 1000;
     text-align: center;
     margin-top: 160px;
}
 h1{
     font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
     font-size: 50px;
     font-weight: 150;
     XXXpadding-top: 300px;
}
 .welcum {
     XXXz-index: 2;
     font-size: 1.4rem;
     font-weight:0;
     font-style: italic;
     color: orangered;
     font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
 html{
     scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
 a {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     margin-left: 30px;
     padding: 7px;
     font-size: 22px;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
}
 .textov{
     justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
   <a href="#welcome-section">About</a>
   <a href="#projects">Work</a>
   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</nav>
<header  id="welcome-section">
   <h1 class="title">Hey I am Matija</h1>
   <p class="welcum">a web developer</p>
</header>
<div id="projects">
   <h3 class="textov">My Projects</h3>
</div>
```